# Second child of an Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, operands

With these emac lisp definitions given to me I need to get the correct results for (defun operand (n ast)). Currently, the first child works like it's supposed to but for the second child (operand (- n 1) (cadr ast)) gives the second child as (INT_LITERAL pos) and not the rest of the child ((INT_LITERAL pos) (77)). Not sure where to go from here. As you can see I've done some guess and testing to fix my solution but nothing has worked yet. From my understanding when my results are nil that means that frame has no parent frame but I'm not sure why it does not print out the whole operand.

```
(defun store (offset value alist)
"Insert the value for this offset, replacing the previous value (if any)."
(cond
   ((null alist)             (list (cons offset value)))    ; ((offset . value))
   ((eq offset (caar alist)) (cons (cons offset value) (cdr alist)))
   (t                        (cons (car alist)
                                   (store offset value (cdr alist))))
   )
)

(defun lookup (offset alist)
"Return the value associated with this offset, or raise an error."
(cond
   ((null alist)             (user-error "UNINITIALISED %s" offset) (exit))
   ((eq (caar alist) offset) (cdar alist))
   (t                        (lookup offset (cdr alist)))
   )
)

;;(setq a (store 1 19 (store 0 17 ())))
;; a
;; (setq a (store 2 20 a))
;; (setq a (store 1 29 a))
;; (lookup 3 ())
;; (lookup 3 a)
;;(lookup 1 a)


;;; Accessors for the various fields in an AST node

(defun position (ast)
"The position stored in an AST node"
(cadar ast)
)

(defun kind (ast)
(caar ast)
)


(defun operand (n ast)
;; Your code goes here.
(if (eq n 0)
      (caadr ast) ;;first child
    (operand (- n 1)(cadr ast)) ;;second child
    )
)

;;(operand (- n 1)(cadr (cadr ast))) gives 77 (#o115, #x4d, ?M)
;;(operand (- n 1)(cadr ast)) gives (INT_LITERAL pos)
;;(operand (- n 1) (cadr (cddr ast))) gives nil
;;(operand (- n 1) (cdr (cadr ast))) gives nil
;; (operand (- n 1)(caddr ast)) gives nil
;;(operand (- n 1)(car ast)) gives wrong type argument listp, pos
;;(operand (- n 1)(cdr ast)) gives nil
;;cadadr, cadr, cadddr, cdadr, caddr, car, cdr

;; (setq ast '((PLUS pos) (( (VARIABLE pos) (b 1) ) ((INT_LITERAL pos) (77) ) ) ))
;; (kind ast) = PLUS
;; (position ast) = pos
;; (operand 0 at) = ((VARIABLE pos)(b 1))
;; (kind (operand 0 ast))= VARIABLE
;; (operand 1 ast)= supposed to equal ((INT_LITERAL pos) (77))
;; (kind (operand 1 ast)) = supposed to equal INT_LITERAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not easy to follow -- I'm confident that you could pare all that code down to something *far* more minimal for these purposes.

At present you're calling `operand` recursively, but the `ast` data does not have the nested structure required by that recursion, and so things quickly break down.

I think you just want this?

```el
(defun operand (n ast)
  (nth n (cadr ast)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and for helping me figure this out! Makes so much sense now